# Identify String A and String B in String C Java

Tags: java, string, merge, substring, character

I have two strings A and B and then a third string C that is a merged version of String A and String B maintaining their order.

For example String A = 'chocolate' and String B = 'chips' and String C = 'cchocholaiptes'. We can identify String B in String C by making the characters of String B uppercase in String C making String C = 'CchocHolaIPteS'.

I am trying to write an algorithm that can go through the String C and identify the characters that are String A and keep them lowercase and the characters of String B and make them uppercase. There are some catches, though. The ordering of String A and String B must be maintained when editing the characters. For example String C could not = 'CcHocholaIPteS' because if we extract the lowercase letters to make String A from String C it would = 'cocholate' instead of 'chocolate'.

In some cases, there may be more than one way to identify the two strings. For example, the strings 'ab' and 'ac' may be indeitifed in the string 'aabc' by assigning the first a to string A (aAbC) or by assigning the first a to string B (AabC). Should this happen, assign the letter to string B; i.e., the correct answer would be AabC.

The algorithm that I have thus far is only partially working and needs improvement to fully work. In my algorithm it goes through String C and just makes uppercase any occurence of the characters of String B and does not necessarily maintain the correct order of String A.

Here is the code for it:

```
private static String getUpper (String B, String C) {

        StringBuilder fixedString = new StringBuilder("");
        StringBuilder bCopy = new StringBuilder(B);

        for (int i = 0; i < C.length(); i++) {

            if (bCopy.length() > 0 && bCopy.charAt(0) == C.charAt(i)) {
                fixedString.append(Character.toUpperCase(C.charAt(i)));
                bCopy.deleteCharAt(0);
            }
            else
                fixedString.append(C.charAt(i));
        }

        return fixedString.toString();
    }
```

When using the following test cases (the first string is string A, the second is String B, and the third String C) the immediate following results is what this algorithm produces.

Input:

```
chocolate chips cchocholaiptes
chocolate chips chocolatechips
chocolate chips cchhoicposlate
chocolate chips chipschocolate
ababc babd ababdbabc
ababc babd ababcbabd
```

Results:

```
CcHocholaIPteS
CHocolatechIPS
CcHhoIcPoSlate
CHIPSchocolate
aBABDbabc
aBABcbabD
```

These results are incorrect in some places though and that can be confirmed with the following correct results:

```
CchocHolaIPteS
chocolateCHIPS
CcHhoIcPoSlate
CHIPSchocolate
aBABDbabc
ababcBABD
```

Any suggestions on code modifications to help solve this problem?

Comment: I think you need to use string A as well.

Comment: _keep them lowercase_  are A B and C always lowercase strings?